# Workflow to send an email to the users within the record is shared

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I am using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 on-premise version.

I created a custom entity(News).
The use of this entity: the system administrator can share records(News) with selected System users.

My question: 
How to send Email Notification (to selected users) on Record Sharing?

Comment: Hi Mouhie, could you please rephrase your question, i couldn't quite understand the last part

Comment: Hi Jason, i already edited my post.

Comment: Just make News an activity entity, SysAdmin then can pick users as Activity Parties and they will see it under Activities views. No need to share data or write code

Comment: But in add to that, i want to send emails to concerned users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any built in functionality to run a workflow on users who are selected in the record sharing form/window.  If you wanted users to be able to run a workflow to send email for a particular record based on who it was shared to, you would need to have a CRM plugin written and/or a custom web resource built if you wanted this to be more of a manual process that is sent when a user says to run the workflow vs. the plugin which can be setup to run all the time when a record is shared to another user.

Below are a few links of with some example CRM plugin code that has been written to send email out to users for whom a record has been shared to them.

https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1b40cb49-d62c-4a71-9282-a9a8b255446d/send-email-to-shared-users?forum=crm

https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68fc025e-360f-4afc-af72-d59c0665a099/to-send-email-to-shared-users-with-whom-the-lead-is-shared-in-ms-crm-2011?forum=crm

https://parthimscrm.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/send-email-user-team-while-sharing-record-crm-2011/

Comment: Thank you Chad for your answe. By the way, have you got a link or something to begin with (Message/event in the plugin...)?

Comment: I added a few links where there's some example plugin code that should help get you or your developers started.  Hope this helps.

Comment: You can also write a custom workflow assembly that you can call from the workflow that will get you the people to put in the to field of the email.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309745.aspx These behave like a plugin snippet and allow you to use the output in workflow steps.